# Capturing CTS frame with Scapy and python

Tags: python, scapy

I have my WiFi card in monitoring mode and listening packages from Python with Scapy. I'm also sending RTS request and hoping to pickup CTS reply but it never happens. (I expect it to be `type 1, subtype=12`.)
Am I sending RTS package the right way? (MAC is just sample). Should I use `rt1()` instead of `sendp()` to get response and how? (I only find samples with IP and I have just a MAC)

```
Doto11 = Dot11(type=1, subtype=11, addr1="ee:11:ee:11:ee:12", ID=0x99)
pkt = RadioTap()/Doto11
sendp(pkt, iface=wlan1mon, realtime=True)
```